# How can I print out the images within a vector of strings?

Tags: c++, json

I am having issues with an assignment from class. We are provided with website that on the backend has several images of various animals. We are supposed to be able to type in the name of the animal and the pictures corresponding to the name of the animal will appear below. This is all within a search.h file and in C++.

The professor went over the topic very quickly in lecture with not much explanation on how to continue. I have been searching for possible solutions to get data from a vector and have tried using map operations but to no avail. I am not very familiar with C++. I will provide the code below. What steps shall I take next?

```
#include <server.h>



ucm::json big5;

std::vector<std::string> lions = {"lion-1.jpeg", "lion-2.jpeg", "lion-3.jpeg", "lion-4.jpeg"};
std::vector<std::string> rhinos = {"rhino-1.jpeg", "rhino-2.jpeg", "rhino-3.jpeg", "rhino-4.jpeg"};
std::vector<std::string> buffalos = {"buffalo-1.jpeg", "buffalo-2.jpeg", "buffalo-3.jpeg", "buffalo-4.jpeg"};
std::vector<std::string> elephants = {"elephant-1.jpeg", "elephant-2.jpeg", "elephant-3.jpeg", "elephant-4.jpeg"};
std::vector<std::string> leopards = {"leopard-1.jpeg", "leopard-2.jpeg", "leopard-3.jpeg", "leopard-4.jpeg"};

void init(){
    big5["lion"] = lions;
    big5["rhino"] = rhinos;
    big5["buffalo"] = buffalos;
    big5["elephant"] = elephants;
    big5["leopard"] = leopards;
}

ucm::json search(std::string key){

    
    // Provide your code here
    // This function should return a specific animal category, specified by key
    // The function should return an appropriate message if the key is not found


}

ucm::json getAll(){
    // This should return all the data we have
    ucm::json temp;
    temp["lion"] = big5["lion"];
    return big5;
}
```

Again I'm not asking for the solution but just a starting point.

Comment: What is `ucm::json`? By the way `std::string key` should probably be `const std::string& key`.

Comment: I believe that is what gives me access to the server. ucm is the name of my school.

Comment: If you have access to `ucm::json` documentation, you need to check if you can iterate over such an object. You need information on what operations the object allows you to perform.

Comment: Do you have a link to `ucm::json` sources?

Comment: oh i see and i don't believe so no, I have to connect to the server locally

Comment: Does your instructor expect you to guess the operations available on big5?

Comment: There are several files attached to this website. If you're referring to the src folder yes I have access to that. Otherwise I am not too sure where to locate the ucm::json soruces.

Comment: Try with server.h, which you are including. Or link us to slides of the lecture.

Comment: Oh my was able to figure it out! I was stuck trying to figure out where the JSON data was being stored, but it was all in the javascript file(facepalm) and I was able to get it working. Thank you for your assistance!